# Is returning std::pair superior to returning std::vector of size 2?

Tags: c++

The title reflects my question, is returning std::pair any superior to returning std::vector of size 2 ***for same variable types***?

As example;

`return std::make_pair(1, 92);` vs `std::vector<int> myV{1,92}; return myV;`

Comment: It's superior for all types. Returning a pair means that you return two values. It has semantics.

Comment: The same values can be put in a vector, would it make any difference, performance, convenience, etc?

Comment: `std::vector<int> myV{1,92};` does not do what you think it does. See #3 here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: @JesperJuhl I checked #3 but couldn't understand, I suppose I created a vector with `myV[0] = 1` and `myV[1] = 92`, I am not sure about its size.

Comment: @ErdemTuna the constructor you are calling (#3) takes a size (you pass 1) and a value (you pass 92). This means you get a vector of one element with value 92.

Comment: @JesperJuhl are you sure? `std::vector<int> myV{1,92};  std::cout << myV.size() << ' ' << myV.capacity() <<'\n';` prints out `2 2` and elements are correct? I couldn't spot my pitfall.

Comment: @ErdemTuna I missed the fact that you used `{}` rather than `()`. That changes it to ctor #9. My bad.

Comment: I see, a good point to raise awareness nevertheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the choice between these two, i.e. you know you're returning two elements, then - probably, yes. Why?

1. More exact semantics. Returning a vector implies that, potentially, there are many output values.
2. `std::vector` is a "heavier" class - typical implementations allocate memory on the heap for storing element data, even when you only have two small elements.
3. (Minor consideration) Constructing an `std::vector` is a bit tricky and error prone, see @JesperJuhl's comment.

As @Yksisarvinen suggests, `std::array<int, 2>` is also an option to consider, which is at least better than `std::vector<int>`. But often the best thing to do is to define your own structure, with fields having meaningful names, e.g.:

```
struct query_results {
    int num_students;
    int max_grade;
}
```

and if you know the range of possible values is even more limited, that possibly use more specific field types.

Answer (score 2):

It strongly depends on the message you want to convey. Are these two values meaningful on their own? Are they related to each other? Is it a container that just happens to have two values?

In the case these are two values with certain meanings, the superior (easier to read) way is to return a small `struct` with two named members, or `std::pair` if struct is not possible for some reason.
Examples could be key and value pair (like from `std::map`) or operation result and status.

In the case this are just two values that you want to iterate over or access by index, `std::array<int, 2>` is better than `std::vector`.
Example could be a mathematical vector in 2D space (which you may want to add to another vector).